# Random generation of three-non-collinear and four-non-coplanar points in 3D space

Tags: performance-tuning, random, computational-geometry

Please, take a look to this code. How it can be improved so that the time execution becomes smaller?

```
RandomPoint[range_] := RandomInteger[{-range, range}, 3]

CollinearQ[{ptA_, ptB_, ptC_}] := 
 Simplify[Cross[ptB - ptA, ptC - ptA]] == {0, 0, 0}

NotCollinearWithSetQ[ptP_, pts_] := 
 Not[Apply[Or, Map[CollinearQ[Append[#, ptP]] &, Subsets[pts, {2}]]]]

CoplanarQ[{ptA_, ptB_, ptC_, ptD_}] := 
 Simplify[Det[{ptB - ptA, ptC - ptA, ptD - ptA}]] == 0

NotCoplanarWithSetQ[ptP_, pts_] := 
 Not[Apply[Or, Map[CoplanarQ[Append[#, ptP]] &, Subsets[pts, {3}]]]]

ThreeNotCollinear[range_] := Module[{ptA, ptB, ptC},
  ptA = RandomPoint[range];
  ptB = ptA; While[ptB == ptA, ptB = RandomPoint[range]];
  ptC = ptA; 
  While[CollinearQ[{ptA, ptB, ptC}], ptC = RandomPoint[range]];
  {ptA, ptB, ptC}
  ]

RandomPoints[n_, range_] := Module[{pts, ptP},
  pts = ThreeNotCollinear[range];
  While[Length[pts] < n,
   ptP = RandomPoint[range];
   If[And[NotCollinearWithSetQ[ptP, pts], 
     NotCoplanarWithSetQ[ptP, pts]],
    pts = Append[pts, ptP]
    ]
   ];
  pts
  ]

pts = RandomPoints[40, 100]
```

> ```
> {{-14, 79, -18}, {31, 67, 66}, {-54, 96, 90}, {-82, -32, 91}, {92, -70, 75}, 
>  {-11, -38, -90}, {-87, 91, -3}, {-15, 58, -79}, {-76, 35, 33}, {-48, 50, -77}, 
>  {30, 88, -14}, {24, -88, -92}, {-54, 39, -47}, {2, -28, 76}, {-3, 89, 32}, {65, 0, 59}, 
>  {64, 66, -85}, {54, -3, 76}, {-32, -51, 80}, {57, -50, -91}, {-52, 84, -100}, 
>  {52, 63, 67}, {-87, -81, 95}, {-48, -12, 31}, {-2, 31, -17}, {56, 88, -22}, 
>  {-1, -75, 90}, {36, -84, -70}, {50, -83, 84}, {4, -97, 70}, {67, 70, -61}, 
>  {62, 13, -100}, {17, 77, -14}, {-9, 53, -35}, {12, 45, 62}, {39, -61, -63}, 
>  {-65, 6, 69}, {-60, -54, -49}, {-45, -46, -36}, {61, -60, -15}}
> ```

Comment: Having every 4 points non-coplanar then certainly every 3 are non-collinear.

Comment: Indeed! thanks!